# Decode Base64 string in PHP recieved from JSON post

Tags: php, json, base64, blob, decode

I'm working on a project where i can select an image (simple file select) and send it via JSON to a PHP MySQL insert page.

Upload page looks like this:

```
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var FR = new FileReader();
                FR.onload = function(e) {
                    $('#img').attr("src", e.target.result);
                    var Naam = $('input[type=file]').val();
                    $('#base').text(e.target.result);
                    var Foto = e.target.result;
                    var Barcode = $('#barcode').val();
                    obj['Barcode'] = Barcode;
                    obj['Naam'] = Naam;
                    obj['Foto'] = Foto;

                    //execute ajax send

                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'insert.php',
                        type : 'POST',
                        data : obj,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success : function(msg) {
                            alert("msg");
                        }
                    });

                    //$.post("insert.php", obj, function (data) {}, "json");
                    //alert("msg");
                };
                FR.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

and my PHP page:

```
$Barcode = $_POST["Barcode"];
$Naam = $_POST["Naam"];
$Name = preg_replace('/^.+[\\\\\\/]/', '', $Naam);
$Foto = base64_decode($_POST["Foto"]);

$query = "INSERT INTO voorraad_foto (barbody, location, foto) VALUES ('$Barcode','$Name','{$Foto}')";
$results = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

And my table field is a BLOB.

But when it execute this, everything works fine except that it doesn't insert it as a blob, but pure string

I've tried with removing the

```
preg_replace('#data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $Foto)
```

but doesn't make any difference, same when trying to add headers, but nothing..

What am i doing wrong, or is there something obvious that i'm not getting?

Thx.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your query WILL fail at some point because the raw binary image data (assuming it uploaded at all/correctly) WILL naturally contain `'` and other SQL metacharacters, breaking your query.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the SQL of your voorraad_foto table?

Comment: I will refine it and secure it against injection when it works. just trying to get it to work. And i checked, query works fine, with this image there are no quotes. Tried it with addslashes, same result.

And this is my table query:
CREATE TABLE `voorraad_foto` (
  `barbody` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `location` varchar(255) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin default NULL,
  `foto` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`barbody`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in some kind of way:

I wrote a function that gets the Base64 string, decodes it and writes it to a Temp file.
Then i read that file again and upload that to my databse.
When success, delete the file.

It may not be the most effecient way, but it works!

```
function WriteToImageAndGetData($base64_string, $File) {
//Write to file
$ifp = fopen($File, "wb");
$data = explode(',', $base64_string); //Split Base64 string
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); //Decode Base64 string
fclose($ifp);

//Read from file
$fp = fopen($File, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($File)); //Read file contents
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);
return $data;
```

}

Comment: If you go that way, you should use a real temporary file by using php://temp or php://memory. For more info, see http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php